# How to append text to all existing .txt documents in C#?

Tags: c#, system.io.file, appendtext

So I have this code:

```
class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Set a variable to the My Documents path.
            string mydocpath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);

            var dir = new DirectoryInfo(mydocpath + @"\sample\");
            string msg = "Created by: Johny";

            foreach (var file in dir.EnumerateFiles("*.txt")) 
            {
                file.AppendText(msg); //getting error here
            }
        }
    }
```

And I want to add a footer to all the text file in the sample folder, but I'm getting an error because the AppendText is not accepting a string argument. I was just wondering how do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the streamwriter from AppendText I think:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Set a variable to the My Documents path.
            string mydocpath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);

            var dir = new DirectoryInfo(mydocpath + @"\sample\");
            string msg = "Created by: Johny";

            foreach (var file in dir.EnumerateFiles("*.txt"))
            {
                var streamWriter = file.AppendText(); 
                streamWriter.Write(msg);
                streamWriter.Close();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

`FileInfo.AppendText()` creates a `StreamWriter`, it doesn't append text per se. You want to do this:

```
using (var sw = file.AppendText()) {
    sw.Write(msg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`AppendText` is the extension method for the `StreamWriter`, see the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.file.appendtext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

So you should write these code instead:

```
foreach (var file in dir.EnumerateFiles("*.txt")) 
{
    using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(file.FullName))
    {
        sw.WriteLine(msg);
    }
}
```